# Server-side verification doesn't work

Tags: php, server-side-validation

I have form with client-side verification by jQuery, which works good. But now for security reasons I want to add also server-side verification (php) for users without JavaScript. I created few functions and array "errors", where errors are logged. After submit I want run the verification. If no errors are logged, continue, if there are errors exit the script. But that part doesn't work, it always continue. My script:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        require_once 'verify_form.php';
        $errors = array(
            'username' => null,
            'password1' => null,
            'password2' => null,
            'email1' => null,
            'email2' => null,
            'age' => null

        );
        validate_all($errors);
        if(empty($errors['username']) && empty($errors['password1']) && empty($errors['password2']) && empty($errors['email1']) && empty($errors['email2']) && empty($errors['age'])) {
//do something
        } else {
            $_SESSION['errorsArray'] = $errors;
            header('Location: /registracia');
            exit;
        }  
    }
```

verify_form.php

```
<?php

function validate_all($errors)
{
    validUsername($errors);
    validPassword1($errors);
    validPassword2($errors);
    validEmail1($errors);
    validEmail2($errors);
    validAge($errors);

}

function validUsername($errors)
{
    include 'config.php';
    $username=$_POST['usernameReg'];
    if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
        $errors['username'] = "Zadajte uživateľské meno v rozmedzí 3 - 16 znakov.";
    } 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1) {
            $errors['username'] = "Toto uživateľské meno už niekto používa.";

    }
}

function validPassword1($errors)
{
    $password1=$_POST['password1Reg'];
    $regex = '/^([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[-]|[_]|[/]|[.])+([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[-]|[_]|[/]|[.])+([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[-]|[_]|[/]|[.])$/';
    if (!preg_match($regex, $password1)) {
        $errors['password1'] = 'Vaše heslo obsahuje nepovolené znaky.';
    }
    if (strlen($password1) < 6) {
        $errors['password1'] = 'Heslo musí obsahovať minimálne 6 znakov.';
    }
}

function validPassword2($errors)
{
    $password2=$_POST['password2'];
    if ($password1 != $password2) {
        $errors['password2'] = 'Zadané heslá sa nezhodujú.';
    }

}

function validEmail1($errors)
{
    include 'config.php';
    $email1=$_POST['email1'];
    $regex = "/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/";
    if (!preg_match($regex, $email1)) {
        $errors['email1'] = 'Neplatná e-mailová adresa.';
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email1'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1) {
        $errors['email1'] = "Tento e-mail už niekto používa.";
    }

}

function validEmail2($errors)
{
    $email2=$_POST['email2'];
    if ($email1 != $email2) {
        $errors['email2'] = 'Zadané e-maily sa nezhodujú.';
    }

}

function validAge($errors)
{
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $regex = "/^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])$/";
    if (!preg_match($regex, $age)) {
        $errors['age'] = 'Vek musí byť číslo v rozsahu od 0-99.';
    }

}




?>
```

Why the script always continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the `$errors` array into the `validUsername()` function. The function doesn't actually receive the original array, but instead it gets a *copy* of it. You're modifying the copy, but the original is never modified. Here's a smaller example to show you how this works:

```
function addCheese(Array $arr)
{
    $arr[] = 'cheese';
}

$a = array();
addCheese($a);
var_dump($a);
// Outputs:
// array(0) {
// }
```

One way to fix this would be to modify each validation function to return the modified array:

```
function validSomething($errors)
{
    // ... do validation checks
    return $errors;
}
```

... and then assign the updated version to the external value:

```
function validate_all($errors)
{
    $errors = validUsername($errors);
    $errors = validPassword1($errors);
    $errors = validPassword2($errors);
    $errors = validEmail1($errors);
    $errors = validEmail2($errors);
    $errors = validAge($errors);
    return $errors;
}
```

Alternatively you could return the local array of errors and assemble them together, or just pass by reference (although this might cause other problems later on).

I'd strongly recommend using some sort of framework to do your validation: this will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: Didn't work. Aren't you overwriting the $errors variable again and again in validate_all function?

Comment: Did you remember to make each "valid..." function return the `$errors` array? Each function call adds more error data to the same error array.

Comment: Great... and you changed the code that calls `validate_all($errors);` in the main script to say `$errors = validate_all($errors);` so that you're using the value returned by that function call?

Answer (score 1):

function validEmail2($errors) doesn't make sence... $email1 is not defined and will always be != $_POST['email2']

Comment: This isn't the main problem, but didn't notice that, fixed, thanks.

Comment: Could you try to not check on empty($error['xyz]) and try $error['xyz] !== null

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the valid functions pointers to $errors. For example

function validUsername(&$errors)

Comment: Yes, I did that, but this feature isn't supported in new PHP versions, so it give me error.